# What is the best aws service to host a menu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a food ordering service api. So far I have lambda to process adding items to the cart and process payments. I want to ask before I pick a service to host the menu. I have a csv of menu items that I would like to upload where it has the attributes: name, price, spicy, vegetarian, etc. I was thinking of using DynamoDB, is this the best service for what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Start with your data sitting in a (protected) s3 bucket - you probably aren't going to need a database for such a small amount of data.